# How do I change the DATA TYPE of a cell or group of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a large spreadsheet of data which stubbornly will not change data type.  when I run the type() formula on a cell, it returns the value 1,  and it will not change no matter what I have tried.

This is a problem because I cannot use the data in formula (the data is numerical and wont workin vlookup forumlas)

Is there any way to FORCE these cells to become data type = 1?    i.e. type(cell)= 1?

Comment: There is no reason why numerical data won't work with vlookup formulas.

Comment: Ron, its giving me trouble.  I really hope you can explain why. Right now one set of data is of type 2, and the other of is of type 1 and vlookup will not work.  As i said,  I cannot change the types of data in bulk--- which is what i am trying to figure out how to do.   Thanks for any insight

Comment: It is simpler to change the text numbers to numeric numbers

Comment: I use =VLOOKUP(  A1 & "",D:E, 2, FALSE ) or =VLOOKUP( A1 + 0,C:D, 2, FALSE ) when looking up text/numbers in a range where the data may be incorrectly formatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your now stated problem with VLOOKUP, I would recommend changing the text values that look like numbers, to numbers.  One way to do this:

- Select a blank cell
- Edit/Copy
- Select the range to be converted to numbers
- Edit/Paste Special / Add

Comment: assuming i have a large sheet of existing data,  and I cannot change the data type by highlighting it and it would be prohibitiely time consuming to re type each cell--- is there a way to do it in bulk?

Comment: The answer to your question is **Yes**.  The specifics, obviously, would depend on your requirements.

Comment: Ron, you're my hero right now.  What a simple and brilliant solution,  I can't believe i I didn't think of that.   I tried that and It worked!

Comment: Glad to help.  I would appreciate it if you could mark my response as the answer.

Comment: I tried, but it won't let me mark answers because my reputation is too low.  sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This solution did not work for me on my spreadsheet so I had to use some formulas to accomplish the task.  I used the following get the text converted to a number and then copied it back to the column.

Example:

`_$_2100.00`

`=NUMBERVALUE(MID(E65,2,10))`

I could not just use `=NUMBERVALUE(E65)` because it returned a `#VALUE!` error because the place that I got the numbers from had a leading space in the cell so I had to use the `Mid()` function to deal with the leading space.  BTW the `TRIM()` function would not work either.

Just something else to try if the first option doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the cells/column, click on Text to Columns, remove any delimiters that could split up the cell, and select the data type. It will force change the data type for that column

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).